# three.js, textures won't load in codepen

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, texture-mapping

I'm starting to learn three.js, I'm doing it on codepen.io. The problem is that I try to add a texture to my boxgeometry and it does not appear, what is the problem with my code?

```
const cubetexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vixO.png');

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 )
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: cubetexture } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.rotateY(Math.PI / 3);
scene.add(cube)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is being blocked because Imgur does not specify a [CORS policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Due to security reasons, modern browsers will refuse to load the image, as evident in the developer console:

[image: Chromium console displaying failed image fetching]

In this case, the easiest solution would be to re-upload your image to Imgur through the main site, and use the URL from there. `i.stack.imgur.com` (images uploaded through Stackoverflow) does not send the required CORS headers, but `i.imgur.com` (images uploaded through [the main site](https://imgur.com/upload)) does.

Comment: The problem is that I try with an image of an example of three.js mapping and it didn’t work

Comment: Modern versions of three.js are supposed to work around this CORS issue automatically, but I personally couldn't get it work, if that's what you're referring to - maybe this is an issue with codepen.io